Alternatives for "abandon a habit"

Children used to go to libraries a lot 10 years ago when the internet wasn't that popular. But nowadays, they've abandoned that habit completely.

I think that "abandon a habit" might not be a correct collocation. Is there a better alternative to it in this situation?

There's been a significant usage shift over the past century. These days we normally quit [bad] habits, rather than abandon them.

Or give them up.

I’d note though that many of today’s children hadn’t been born 10 years ago. And it would be at least a bit odd to describe those children as having abandoned the habit. And most of the individuals who were children 10 years ago are no longer children today. Anyway, I suspect you mean something like Unlike the children of 10 years ago, today’s kids don’t go to libraries a lot.

Given the choice of characterizing "spending (too much) time at the Library" or "spending (too much) time on the Internet," as a habit bad enough to be worthy of abandoning/breaking/kicking, I would go with the latter.  Who knows ... ten years hence, your question might be:...."Children used to avoid libraries a lot 10 years ago when the internet was very addictive and still popular. But nowadays, they/today's kids have abandoned/broken/kicked that habit completely."

how about abandoned that activity or stopped that practice

It looks fine to me.  If you want an alternative, then "lost that habit" or "got out of that habit" are possible, but not better.

to abandon a habit is to give it up, to stop doing it.
