I got something for you
Context : I found that my friend have been sad recently. I decided to buy a gift for her to surprise and make her happy again. Now, I meet her in our class. I give it to her and say:

Me: How are you? Hey, I got something for you. I think that this will
help you feel better.
( then, I give it to her)
My friend: Thank you so much.

(1) I got something for you= I now have (in possession) something (a gift) for you, and I will give it to you.
=> "got" here is slang of "have" and "have got" and "in possession"
(2) I got something for you= I got ( past tense of "get") something in the past, now I give it to you.
=>" got" here is the past form of "get".
In this context, when my friend hears this sentence "I got something for you", my friend doesn't know If I am using the meaning as (1) or (2). Right?

It's ambiguous. But equally if you said "I bought you a present" they wouldn't know if you had the present with you. If you say "I got something for you. I'll give you it tonight." (or "I bought you a present. I'll give you it tonight.") then they know you don't have it. If you say "Wait, I got something for you!" (or "Wait, I bought you a present...") it implies you're going to give them it right then.

@StuartF, I give my friend the gift right After I say that sentence ""I got something for you".
So, does the listener know the meaning of "got" (1) or (2)?

you would have to ask the listener if she knows what you mean specifically

Does this answer your question? I got something for you. "Got" means "brought" or " have- possession"

Related: "got somebody something" vs "have got somebody something" "got something" vs "have got something" and Use "got" or "have got"? and Do 'have got' and 'got' have the same meaning in American English?

Just want to point out that saying "I got something" with the meaning "I have something here" is bad English. It might be heard from native speakers, but it sounds completely uneducated.

If I heard “I(’ve) got something for you”, I would automatically assume got referred to possession here. It can refer to the process of obtaining as well, but it would be vastly more common in that case to say, “I got you something” (which cannot refer to possession). So I would say your example is almost certain to be understood as (1), unless context dictates otherwise.

In American English, I got is either simple past tense:

I got some cough medicine for you when I was at the pharmacy.

or non-standard present tense meaning "I have":

I got something for you. Guess which hand it's in.

Standard would be:

I've got something for you. Guess which hand it's in.


yes, But I would like to know, in this context, Does the listener know which meaning of "got" in that sentence I am using. (1) or (2)?

The listener would know only if they use "got" in the same way you do, or if they speak standard English but happen to know already, or can tell from how you speak, that you use non-standard constructions.

If I and my friend both speak non-standard constructions. how can my friend know which meaning of "got" I am using?

If you don't add a phrase like "when I was at the pharmacy" and are known to speak non-standard English, your statement would be ambiguous.  It would not be clear whether you were saying "I have something" or "I obtained something".

Do English Native speakers often use "got" slang with the meaning of "have" and "own" in daily conversations?

It is not slang. It is dialect. Standard dialect vs a non-standard dialect.

what is the difference between slang and dialect? Is that slang is common in daily conversation, but dialect is common only in a group of people?

Did you mean that only several regions use "got" with the meaning as "have " and "own"?

One difference is that slang tends to be  relatively ephemeral and generational, whereas dialect variants tend to be intergenerational and persistent over a much longer time, often hundreds of years rather than mere decades.  Dialect can be very broadly spoken -- by millions of people. Or it can be confined to a small area. There can be subdialects within a dialect.

Some English-speaking countries or regions use "got" with the meaning "have" and "own", other English-speaking countries or regions don't. Right?

Yes, in some dialects of English "got" is a synonym for "have".  Dialects are not always regional, though they may have originally been confined to a region. The situation is complicated by diaspora.

I find it hard to imagine an AAVE speaker including have (contracted or not) in I got something for you. Which as you say is dialect, not "slang". I stand to be corrected, but imho only context establishes whether I got $5 means I came into possession of / was paid $5 (in the past) or I am in possession of / have / own $5 (right now).

@FumbleFingers I've got something for you is something you'd hear  anywhere in the US. Although it's informal, it is, as I said, standard AmE, not non-standard, and not regional.  I got your moonshine with me in the truck, now pay up (where it has a present tense sense) is non-standard.

@FumbleFingers https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sca_esv=31a3dd54a4fd3d08&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&sxsrf=ADLYWIIQacWmoXwyycE64Kz_KL1PiKUW8w:1716226676398&q=%22I%27ve+got+something+for+you%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&prmd=visnbmt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiE7ZnL4pyGAxUrFVkFHRA8BMIQ0pQJegQIeRAB&biw=1366&bih=681&dpr=1

None of that makes much sense to me. I can't tell if you're disagreeing with me, or giving additional information. I'm sure I've got something for you is only "informal" in AmE insofar as it includes a contraction (in my experience, Americans rarely use I have something for you, which is the relatively formal BrE version).. But my point was simply that (with or without got, contracted or not) AAVE doesn't use have in that way (much, if at all).

@FumbleFingers  Let's make it really clear. You're wrong. No one said anything about AAVE but you, BTW.  That's your particular go-to example for "dialect" not mine.

"I got five dollars in my shirt pocket" is not standard AmE but non-standard. Standard is "I've got five dollars in my shirt pocket."  And you're wrong that Americans rarely say "I have something for you". Where are you getting this stuff??  What makes you think you know what is rarely coming out of the mouths of AmE speakers?

"I have something for you".  https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sca_esv=75ce3f1a0c12c434&sca_upv=1&sxsrf=ADLYWILcH70I3KS8kT-PzVGCmZhRoGhS4Q:1716231559439&q=%22I+have+something+for+you%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&prmd=ivsnbmt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjuks_j9JyGAxX9kIkEHRkKCrwQ0pQJegQIdBAB&biw=1259&bih=744&dpr=1.1

Google Gemini says AAVE is more likely to use "I got something for you" than "I have got something for you"., which I believe more than I believe you. It goes on to say...

" Here's why:
Simplicity: AAVE often favors simpler verb conjugations. "Got" in this context functions as the past participle of "get" and eliminates the need for the auxiliary verb "have."

Origin: AAVE has roots in African American communities in the Southern US, where this construction is more commonplace.

Informality: AAVE is a generally informal dialect, and "I got something for you" aligns with that tone.

While "I have got something for you" is grammatically correct, it's less common in AAVE due to the reasons mentioned above.*

@FumbleFingers I said nothing about AAVE in my answer, so I don't know why you're even going there. I said that "I've got" is STANDARD AmE, not a non-standard dialect form of AmE. And I showed you plenty of examples of that. But do you even bother to acknowledge hard evidence? No.  You're accusing me of making statements that I did not make.

I have had a lot of trouble constantly saying on this site that I've got OR I have are perfectly natural in AmE, JUST LIKE BrE. And yes, why even get into AAVE? That use of I got is just like all other informal AmE. So, I am upvoting this answer even though mine was downvoted!

@LEHANH Context matters. For example, if I walk up to you and say this, the odds are good that I have arrived to give you something. If we've been sitting together for hours and I say this, it becomes more likely that I'm simply relaying something that happened in the past. Unless I just got up and got my bag, at which point... This is why context matters.

If I got is construed to somehow be a first person present tense form, then why do we not see he gots in the third person present tense? And what's its past tense?

@tchrist But we do indeed hear "he gots" in non-standard dialects. "He gots to go".  https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sca_esv=fdd505efaadfc2c0&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&sxsrf=ADLYWILXkrIGE4O_H1V5UlAiyIoclCXsHQ:1716303226199&q=%22he+gots+to+go%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&prmd=ivsnbmt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie4_7g_56GAxVuFlkFHcvWC1MQ0pQJegQIVRAB&biw=1366&bih=681&dpr=1

@tchrist and this: https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sca_esv=fdd505efaadfc2c0&sca_upv=1&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&sxsrf=ADLYWILLE88vD6fvnXhC9qz87NOu2sxT-w:1716303504563&q=%22he+gots+his%22&tbm=bks&source=lnms&prmd=ivsbmnt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmh93lgJ-GAxVRlIkEHZXmB0EQ0pQJegQIVRAB&biw=1366&bih=681&dpr=1

@tchrist  But there are also non-standard dialects where "he got" is present tense.  He got something wrong with his leg.

@TimR Then again, we also see I/you/we/they gots in the same contexts – in fact, some of them more commonly than he gots, I’d say. Your search for ‘he gots his’ in Google Books yields 68 hits, whereas ‘I gots my’ yields 420, which would seem to agree with that. I don’t think we can meaningfully plump this presential got(s) verb into any existing category, precisely because it behaves to unusually, with -s in all persons. I won’t call it a reanalysed base form, ’cause the past tense is still got (never heard *gotsed), and there’s no new 3s he *gotses either (unless you’re Gollum).

@tchrist Boy, is that an easy one. Those who use got to mean have/have got, also you use it for simple past. And, by the way, those who use I, he, she, it. you, they gots would be identified as southern black american. Except you forgot the me: I gots me a new car.

Yes I've got something for you. in AmE = I have something for you. and right, it is not non-standard and not regional. It's omnipresent in AmE and BrE, too.
AND:
And "I got something for you." can be three things:

non-standard for have/have got, meaning: in someone's possession

_ the past tense of get where get means to buy or obtain or receive.
I got something for you can have three different meanings:
I bought something for you. [like a thing at a shop]
I received something for you. [like a letter or package in the mail]
I obtained something for you. [like a rare book from a book dealer]

I have upvoted your answer as well. Wasn't my downvote.

@TimR It's really too much. Getting fed up with these misplaced dv's. :) Look at this one, too: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/352337/alternatives-for-abandon-a-habit/352340#352340 Is there anything intrinsically wrong with it?

It's a correct explanation of what it means to "abandon a habit". Maybe it was downvoted by someone who though that what was being described by the OP wasn't really a "habit".

@Lambie, your answer have the same content as my question that "got" is non-standard for have/have got, meaning: in someone's possession and "got" is also the past tense of get where get means to buy or obtain or receive.
But the thing I want to ask is if the listener know which meaning of "got" the speaker is using.

@Lambie, in case both speaker and the listener use slang. If the listener knows which meaning the speaker is using?

Stray downvotes happen.  I have clicked on it by mistake when I wanted an upvote, then noticed later when I couldn't change it.

@LEHANH To repeat, "got"  is not slang. It is not confined to a particular group or age-group; nor is it a coinage; nor is it subject to growing stale and dated as slang is.  It is a cross-dialect, cross-generation verb used mainly in informal contexts, though that is no doubt the result of the educational system. Whoever has taught you that this is slang doesn't understand what slang is. Get that into your noggin.
